# Flag a cell and return a var from chosen cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very small data base (100-200 rows) of data that I need to work with. Column K is an expiration date. I would like to flag any dates that are either expired or two weeks from being expired. Once that cell is flagged I would then like to pull the data into the TextBody from the code that I have written to send an email to myslef to inform me of the expiration as well as the data correlating to the expiration.

```
    Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    objMessage.Subject = "Clumpy Milk Ahead"
    objMessage.From = """Expired Milk"" <omg@lol.com>"
    objMessage.To = "lol@lol.com"
    objMessage.TextBody = "Place pulled data here"
```

Ultimately I need a message that looks sort of like this...

```
set Referencing_Expiration_Cell As RFC

  Brand: (RFC col A) 
  Type: (RFC col d) 
  Shipment: (RFC col E) 
  Distributor: (RFC col F)
  Pickup Driver: (RFC col H)
  Employee: (RFC col I)
  Expiration Date: (RFC col K)
```

This code will be placed on a button to run daily. So automation is not needed for the script. Any help with this would be very much appreciated. I have been working on some different strings of code and cannot for the life of me to get what my mind is going for down so that everything runs smoothly.

Thanks in advance for any information/help!!

Comment: Are you getting an error with what you tried?  If so what is the error  and where does it occur in your code?

Comment: I am getting no error within the code in the message or the additional code for sending the email via authentication. I am having trouble getting the information to populate for me for the email message. I guess I am wondering what direction to go in getting this type of project setup. My guess was to set certain variables for the type of information needed in the email, these variables selected by the flagged date automatically and then populate in the email. which path to take is where I am struggling. WorkFlow, is what I would label it as..
-Jgr3g

Comment: did my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19432705/2145211) help?  Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an assumption that your question is asking how to pull values in a row to use in VBA.  The following code will retrieve the values one row at a time.  It assumes your data starts in A2 and has at least 2 rows of data

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim endCell, currentCell As range
Set currentCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").range("A2")
Set endCell = currentCell.End(xlDown)

Do

     brand = currentCell.Value
     myType = currentCell.Offset(0, 3).Value 'Offset moves a column over to B in this case
     shipment = currentCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
     distributer = currentCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
     driver = currentCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
     employee = currentCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
     ExpireDate = currentCell.Offset(0, 9).Value

     If ExpireDate < Today() + 14

        'Do Stuff here

     End If

    Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(1, 0) 'Offset moves to the next row down in this case

Loop Until currentCell = endCell.Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```